# Prove that $\lim_{}\left ( \frac{2n}{n+2} \right ) =2$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

Please check my proof

$$\frac{2n}{n+2}-2< \epsilon $$

$$\frac{2n-2n-4}{n+2}< \epsilon  $$

$$ 4\left |\frac{-1}{n+2}  \right |< \epsilon $$

If we choose $N\leq n$

Because

$$4\left |\frac{-1}{n+2}  \right |\leq \frac{4}{N+2}$$

and

$$ \frac{4}{N+2}<\frac{4}{N}<\epsilon $$

by transitivity property

$$4\left | \frac{-1}{n+2} \right |< \epsilon $$

Then limit is true

Comment: The numerator in the second line should be $2n-2n-4$. Moreover you should put the absolute value on the left already in the first line. Lastly you have to declare what $N$ you pick, in order of the inequality $\frac{2}{N}<\varepsilon$ to hold.

Comment: Do I must declare what $N$ I pick everytime I prove?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/943182/prove-lim-n-to-infty-frac2nn2-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ given.

if we put $N=\lfloor \frac{4}{\epsilon} \rfloor+1$, then

$$\forall n \geq N \;\;  n>\frac{4}{\epsilon}$$

$\implies$

$$\forall n\geq N \;\;  \frac{4}{n}<\epsilon$$

$\implies$

$$\forall n\geq N\;\; |\frac{2n}{n+2}-2|<\frac{4}{n}<\epsilon.$$

$\implies$

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{2n}{n+2}=2.$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative proof:

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{2n}{n+2}\right)=$

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{2n}{n+2}\cdot\frac{1/n}{1/n}\right)=$

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{2}{1+2/n}\right)=$

$\frac{2}{1+\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(2/n)}=$

$\frac{2}{1+0}=$

$2$